# How to open native HTML dialog from a parent component in Angular?

Tags: html, angular, dialog

In my Angular app I have a home (parent) component that I'm displaying a modal in:

```
<button>
    New message
</button>

<app-modal modalTitle="New message">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nam nihil
    dignissimos cumque provident eius id magnam blanditiis saepe. Reiciendis
    inventore nihil modi eveniet laborum quidem quo labore minima porro?
    Laudantium.
  </p>
  <div modalFooter>
    <button>Custom button</button>
  </div>
</app-modal>
```

The modal component is:

```
<dialog #modal class="max-w-screen-xl border rounded-t-lg">
<button (click)="modal.close()">
rest of markup....
</dialog>
```

When clicking the `New message` button in the parent component, I want to call the `openModal()` method on the `<dialog>` element in the modal component.

I have tried using an `EventEmitter` and `Output` but it didn't work.

What is the common way to do something like this in Angular?

Answer (score 3):

**I guess one of approaches is:**

In your parent component.ts:

```
...
isShowModalInChildComponent = false;

openModalWindowInChildComponent(): void {
  isShowModalInChildComponent = true;
}
...
```

In your parent component.html:

```
...
<button (click)="openModalWindowInChildComponent()">
    New message
</button>

<app-modal 
  [isShowDialog]="isShowModalInChildComponent"
  modalTitle="New message"
>
  ...
</app-modal>
```

In your modal component.ts:

```
@Input('isShowDialog')
set _isShowDialog(data: boolean) {
  this.isShowDialog = data;
}
isShowDialog = false;
```

In your modal component.html:

```
<dialog 
  #modal 
  *ngIf="isShowDialog"
  class="max-w-screen-xl border rounded-t-lg"
>
  <button (click)="modal.close()">
  rest of markup....
</dialog>
```

Comment: I think event better would be to do something like [this](https://netbasal.com/create-a-dialog-component-using-the-native-dialog-element-in-angular-321aeda2908f). With this approach you have easier access to html dialog element

Answer (score 1):

I have done native HTML dialogs in Angular apps for a bit. My approach is usually something like this:

**my-component.html**

```html
<button (click)="open()"> Open Dialog </button>

<dialog #mydialog>
  <p>
    Some text here
  </p>
  <button (click)="close()"> Close Dialog </button>
</dialog>
```

**my-component.ts**

```js
class MyComponent {
  @ViewChild('mydialog') myDialog: HTMLElement;

  open() {
    this.myDialog.nativeElement.showModal()
  }

  close() {
    this.myDialog.nativeElement.close()
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you but since the `dialog` element is in a child component. How would you expose the `#myDialog` ref to the parent from child? Can it be done using `@ViewChild`?

Comment: Does the parent need direct access to the `dialog`? Or can it call the `open`/`close` methods of the child through the `@ViewChild`?

Comment: I was able to use two `@ViewChild` to expose the native method of the `dialog` element. But I guess you're right, it's probably enough to call the child methods which themselves interact with the native dialog element.